# Product Title based on EAV

Tags: magento-1.7, backend, products-management, eav

I kept looking for days to find a way to fill the product title (in the backend product add/edit form) field automatically based on values that i choose on different custom attributes.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Yes, for example i have a tire as a product and i want to have its name generated as "Width/AspectRatio"R"RimSize Brand Model ..." where Width, AspectRatio, Rimsize, Brand and Model are Extra product attributes. So when i save the product its name gets filled with the attributes value that i have set.

Answer (score 1):

You can observe the event `catalog_product_save_before` and construct the name based on the attributes you need.

Here is a small example on how the observer method could look.

```
public function generateName($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $newName = $product->getWidth(). ' - '.$product->getAspectRatio().' - '....//all attributes you need
    $product->setName($newName);
    return $this;
}
```

This could work if when you save the product from the backend, but I don't think it will work if you import products.

Comment: Yeah that would be a good question, probably you have to save again every imported product or maybe "update attributes" might work.